# Implementing Django Bootstrap crispy forms into default signup / login pages?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, bootstrap-5, django-crispy-forms

I've set up user account signup and login pages following [this tutorial](https://learndjango.com/tutorials/django-login-and-logout-tutorial) and it all works great, except the pages have no formatting. I'm now looking for a simple drop in solution to improve the appearance of "templates/registration/login.html" and "templates/registration/signup.html". Someone recommended crispy forms which look great, and as the rest of my site uses Bootstrap 5, [crispy-bootstrap5](https://github.com/django-crispy-forms/crispy-bootstrap5) looks ideal.

I'm struggling to implement crispy-bootstrap5 as I don't understand Django's inbuilt `django.contrib.auth.forms` nor forms in general, and can't find simple reproducible examples for crispy forms with signup.html and login.html. I've [installed packages](https://github.com/django-crispy-forms/crispy-bootstrap5#usage) fine, but now don't know how to beautify login.html and signup.html from that tutorial:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}Sign Up{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
  <h2>Sign up</h2>
  <form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit">Sign Up</button>
  </form>
{% endblock %}
```

I don't know where to go with this, but the docs for [regular django-crispy](https://github.com/django-crispy-forms/django-crispy-forms#example) links to [a gist for an eg form](https://gist.github.com/maraujop/1838193), and the index.html `{% load crispy_forms_tags %}` and `{% crispy form %}`. I've put them in which mostly left the page unchanged except for messing up the formatting. I think I now need to modify `class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm)` in forms.py but I don't know how. I'm also reluctant to risk bigger problems by modifying Django's inbuilt functionalities I don't understand.

What steps need we take to get login.html and signup.html looking like bootstrap 5?

Comment: `{% load crispy_forms_tags %}` then `{{ form|crispy }}` or if you want to render each form field separately `{{ form.username|as_crispy_field }}`

Comment: Could you please confirm where I could insert these? Into login.html?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

please follow bellow steps to use crispy_forms with bootstrap5:

**1st step:** Install `crispy_forms` form bootstrap 5

```
pip install crispy-bootstrap5
```

**step 2:** Add `crispy_forms` and `crispy_bootstrap5` to installed apps

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    "crispy_forms",
    "crispy_bootstrap5",
    ...
)
```

**step 3:** add crispy form attr to `settings` file

```
CRISPY_ALLOWED_TEMPLATE_PACKS = "bootstrap5"

CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = "bootstrap5"
```

check [here](https://github.com/django-crispy-forms/crispy-bootstrap5) for details

to use crispy form in templates, add `{% load crispy_forms_filters %}` and `{% load crispy_forms_tags %}` on top of your `sign up` and `login` page.

and declare form as crispy i.e `{{forms| crispy}}` or field as `{{ form.fieldname|as_crispy_field }}`

Comment: Thank you, but I've already done these steps following [these instructions](https://github.com/django-crispy-forms/crispy-bootstrap5#usage). My issue is idk how to use it to improve these pages. Or have you described all the steps required for this?

Comment: add `{% load crispy_forms_filters %}`  and `{% load crispy_forms_tags %}` on top of your sign up and login page. and declare `form` as crispy i.e `{{forms| crispy}}` or field as `{{ form.fieldname|as_crispy_field }}`

Comment: `{{form|crispy}}` (using `form` not `forms`) works for me.

Comment: The syntax {{ form|crispy }} does not consider Layout. Use {% crispy form %} instead, see [this thread on stackoverflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57507336/python-django-crispy-forms-layout)